# Wireless keyboard / mouse non-responsive for 10 - 15 seconds on resume from sleep

Tags: windows-7, usb, wireless-mouse

Whenever my windows 7 SP1 PC comes out of sleep, my Logitech wireless keyboard and mouse are unresponsive for around 10 - 15 seconds.  Not the end of the world I know, but it never used to do this and I cant for the life of me remember when it started. What I do know is the PC 'beeps' the USB connection sound several times as it is resuming, as if all the USB devices are being reconnected and the wireless systems appears to be last.

So my questions is can any one point me in a direction to see why this behavior is occurring and if if possible can I move the keyboard/mouse up the USB connection queue so they connect first?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a similar experience, I think Windows 7 re-installs the USB and mouse drivers, every freaking time again. It started some weeks ago.

Comment: Interesting - maybe this is as a result of a Windows Update?